# How to run QEMU with Fedora + Custom kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, fedora, qemu, riscv, processor

I am trying to run Fedora with QEMU, but with a custom kernel that i built by using the first steps from the readme.txt file from [here](https://gitlab.com/c-sky/buildroot/-/jobs/1251564514/artifacts/browse/output/images/). The kernel describes T-HEAD's C910 processor, and I want it in order to run benchmarks (Fedora was the first OS that I found that supports RISC-V).

Following the steps from Fedora's guide, QEMU finally successfully booted, but with the guide's suggested kernel. The command run is shown [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Architectures/RISC-V/Installing#Boot_under_QEMU).

```
qemu-system-riscv64 \
-bios none \
-nographic \
-machine virt \
-smp 8 \
-m 2G \
-kernel Fedora-Developer-Rawhide-*-fw_payload-uboot-qemu-virt-smode.elf \
-object rng-random,filename=/dev/urandom,id=rng0 \
-device virtio-rng-device,rng=rng0 \
-device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0 \
-drive file=Fedora-Developer-Rawhide-*.raw,format=raw,id=hd0 \
-device virtio-net-device,netdev=usernet \
-netdev user,id=usernet,hostfwd=tcp::10000-:22
```

Also, the command from the readme.txt file from the first link works as well, but it just boots into the kernel alone, no OS (hence the need for the OS).

```
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./host/lib ./host/csky-qemu/bin/qemu-system-riscv64 -M virt -kernel fw_jump.elf -device loader,file=Image,addr=0x80200000 -append "rootwait root=/dev/vda ro" -drive file=rootfs.ext2,format=raw,id=hd0 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0 -nographic -smp 1
```

I tried modifing the `-kernel` argument from the command at Fedora's guide to the path to the custom kernel. By executing the command, it hangs at the start, as shown in the image below:[image: dump]

It's probably a matter of arguments that are supplied to QEMU since it's clear that the one from readme.txt and the one from Fedora's guide differ by a lot

Answer (score 0):

Build the qemu from https://github.com/T-head-Semi/qemu to run c910 processor. The support is not there in mainline qemu.